# Метод для обхода элементов списка и возврата результата в виде списка значений

Tags: java

Есть такая задачка:

> Написать реализацию метода `getAllValues`, способного обойти все элементы списка, начиная с `element`, и возвращающего результат в виде списка значений.
>   Пример: `{"1"}->{"2"}->{"3"}->{"4"}` преобразовать в `{"1", "2", "3", "4"}`.

```
class Node {
    private Node next;
    private String value;

    public static List<String> getAllValues(Node element) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Как это реализовать? И что значит условие "начиная с element"? Имеется в виду с первого значения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допустим переменная `element = "3"`. Тогда при вызове `getAllValues(element)` должен вернуться список `{"3", "4"}`. Если `element = "2"`, то `{"2", "3", "4"}`.

Comment: Спасибо, стало понятнее. можете еще уточнить что значит {"1"}->{"2"}->{"3"}->{"4"} преобразовать в {"1", "2", "3", "4"} } }?? не понимаю что хотят этим сказать

Comment: Скорее всего первый вариант - это связный список (`LinkedList`), а второй вариант - это `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

По сути, нужно собрать значения (`value`) всех узлов (`Node`) в цепочке. Первым узлом в цепочке является `element`, а последним - очередной узел, полученный с помощью `next` и равный `null`. Если `element` сам равен `null`, то цепочка элементов считается пустой.

В итоге код выглядит так:

```
public static List<String> getAllValues(Node element)
{
    List<String> allValues = new ArrayList<>();
    Node current = element;
    while (current != null)
    {
        allValues.add(current.value);
        current = current.next;
    }
    return allValues;
}
```

При желании `ArrayList` можно заменить на `LinkedList`.

Comment: спасибо, вроде то!